# MySQL Server configuration, is it enough for my needs?

Tags: mysql, microsoft-access, odbc

I've never dealt with MySQL before, so I am very new at this.

I am connecting my MS Access front-end to MySQL server. The server configuration is 2 CPU Cores,  2GB RAM and 60GB SSD. The server has over 200k records, which I and my team will need to look at daily and import more records daily.

Will this be fast enough for 3 people connected to it simultaneously, or should I upgrade the server?

Comment: I disagree with this close vote, although it would be useful if there were more technical information provided.

Comment: Most databases's RAM requirements depend on the used index defined by the tables of your database. For good performance all used index should fit into RAM at the same time.

Answer (score 0):

It is impossible to give a guarantee as it slightly depends on your how the data is represented in the database, however **this should be adequate** - especially if the data is properly indexed (important with the relatively low amount of RAM you have).

Worst case, the database will run slowly and you will need to tune it and/or get more resources.

Comment: Why was this downvoted?